# regex for _number

Tags: php, regex

The following array is coming from $_POST for a PHP web app:

[image]

I'm trying to come up with a way to identify which of the keys ends with underscore and a number and then create a separate multidimensional array for those.  Unfortunately, I'm stuck on the first step of identifying which of the keys ends with underscore and a number.  Here is my experimental code:

```html
  foreach ($values as $k => $v):
   echo $k . '-' . $v . '<br>';
   preg_match_all('!\d+!', $v, $m);
   echo '<pre>' . print_r($m, 1) . '</pre>';
   // echo $m[$k];
  endforeach;
```

And a partial screen shot of the result:

[image]

The end goal is to get something like this as the result:

```
        [scenarioID] => 7
        [comments] => test 1
        [scenarioinserted] => 
        Array
        (
        [0]=>Array
        (
        [itemID]=>100
        [itemvalue]=> 
        ),
        [1]=>Array
        (
        [itemID]=>120
        [itemvalue]=>
        ),
    etc.
```

How can this be accomplished?

**EDIT**
Here was my attempt to set the HTML to `name="itemID[]"` in the PHP code:

```
foreach ($o as $key => $value):
    foreach ($value as $k => $v):
        if (!in_array($key, $calculation)):
            if ($k === 'itemID'):
                //$td[$key][$k] = '<input type="text" name="itemID_' . $i . '" style="width: 3em" readonly="readonly" value=' . $o[$key][$k] . '>'; 
                $td[$key][$k] = '<input type="text" name="itemID[]" style="width: 3em" readonly="readonly" value=' . $o[$key][$k] . '>'; 
            elseif ($k === 'itemvalue'):
                $class = (!empty($errors[$k])) ? ' class="fail" ' : '';
                $td[$key][$k] = '<input type="text" name="itemvalue[]" style="width: 7em"' . $readonly .  $class . ' value="' . $o[$key][$k] . '">';
            else:
                $td[$key][$k] = $v;
            endif;
        else:
            $td[$key][$k] = $v;
        endif;
    endforeach;
endforeach;
```

And a screen shot of the resulting HTML source code:
[image]

**FURTHER EDIT**
The above returns this:

[image]

Brilliant!  Many thanks for the help.  This is *MUCH* better than my original approach.

Comment: Instead of naming your input fields `itemID_0`, `itemID_1` etc name the input fields `name="itemID[]"` then you get an array returned in `$_POST['itemID'`]` and all the work is done for you. Do the same for the `itemValue`

Comment: @RiggsFolly you genius :-)\

Comment: @Dagon No you genius :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly lets go  halves

Comment: Well you gave me an UV and I gave you one. Looks fair to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the form use:

```
name="itemID[]"
```

and

```
name="itemvalue[]"
```

now you have nice arrays to use

Comment: I tried that but the HTML tag in the source code is showing as `name="itemID[]"`.  The PHP code for that (within a couple of foreach loops) is like so `'<input type="text" name="itemID[]" style="width: 3em" readonly="readonly" value=' . $o[$key][$k] . '>'; `  Apparently, I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: im not understanding what the problem is here @knot22

Comment: I will edit the original post and include some screen shots to try and explain it better.

Comment: @knot22 i read the edit, but you dont explain what is NOT working. and you haven't changed itemvalue

Comment: What didn't look right to me was `name="itemID[]"`.  But I think I see it now.  Will re-edit the post with follow up.

Comment: that's what it should be as stated in the answer. did you test it?